# How do I wait for ThreadPoolExecutor.map to finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have the following code, which has been simplified:

```
import concurrent.futures

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

def _exec(x):
    return x + x

myfuturelist = pool.map(_exec,[x for x in range(5)])

# How do I wait for my futures to finish?

for result in myfuturelist:
    # Is this how it's done?
    print(result)

#... stuff that should happen only after myfuturelist is
#completely resolved.
# Documentation says pool.map is asynchronous
```

The documentation is weak regarding ThreadPoolExecutor.map. Help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Difference between map and submit**

[Executor.map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) will run jobs in parallel and wait futures to finish, collect results and return a generator. It has done the wait for you. If you set a timeout, it will wait until timeout and throw exception in generator.

> map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)
>
> - the iterables are collected immediately rather than lazily;
> - func is executed asynchronously and several calls to func may be made    concurrently.

To get a list of futures and do the wait manually, you can use:

```
myfuturelist = [pool.submit(_exec, x) for x in range(5)]
```

[Executor.submit](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) will return a [future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object, call `result` on future will explicitly wait for it to finish:

```
myfuturelist[0].result() # wait the 1st future to finish and return the result
```

**EDIT 2023-02-24**

Although original answer is accepted, plz check mway's and milkice's. I'll try to add some detail here.

[wait](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-functions) is the better way, and it lets you control how to wait the future by parameter **return_when**:

- FIRST_COMPLETED, wait until the first finishes
- FIRST_EXCEPTION, wait until the first raises exception or all finish
- ALL_COMPLETED, wait until all finish

It returns a tuple of finished futures and unfinished ones:

```
# wait first one to finish
finished_set, unfinished_set = wait(myfuturelist, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
# wait all 
wait(myfuturelist, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
```

Using `with` is elegant, but notice that:

- you don't have access to those return values directly (you can workaround though, for example a nonlocal or global variable)
- you need to close the pool, which means you can't reuse it to **save the cost of thread creation and destroy**.

Comment: "the iterables are collected immediately" refers to the iterables *argument* (the iterable of arguments passed to the mapping function). `map` submits tasks immediately, but it does *not* block until all tasks are completed.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer

Answer (score 17):

The call to `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` does *not* block until all of its tasks are complete. Use [wait](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-functions) to do this.

```
from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED
...

futures = [pool.submit(fn, args) for args in arg_list]
wait(futures, timeout=whatever, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)  # ALL_COMPLETED is actually the default
do_other_stuff()
```

You could also call `list(results)` on the generator returned by `pool.map` to force the evaluation (which is what you're doing in your original example). If you're not actually using the values returned from the tasks, though, `wait` is the way to go.

Comment: Noting that @milkice's answer is nice as well--if you create the pool in a `with` block, exiting the block will wait for the tasks to finish without you having to call `wait`, but it will also close the pool.

Comment: It does in fact look like the context manager will close the pool by calling shutdown, but shutdown also changes `executor._shutdown`, which will cause all threads to stop scanning the queue for new work. In other words, if you have more work on the queue than active threads, exiting the context will discard the jobs that have not yet been picked up by a thread worker!

Comment: @CharlBotha I think  that since [`map` calls `.submit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53d9cd95cd91f1a291a3923acb95e0e86942291a/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L608) on all of your tasks, and since `__exit__` calls `shutdown` with [`wait=True`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53d9cd95cd91f1a291a3923acb95e0e86942291a/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L634), everything included in the original `map` call will get joined in `shutdown`, even if the number of tasks >> number of threads. Right? You certainly can't submit tasks to the queue after the context manager exits, though.

Comment: I came back here after some experiments, and yes, you're right. The behaviour I was seeing, was because tasks, during their running, were adding more tasks to the executor. The TPE context would exit, and those subtasks would get discarded. A bit of an edge case. Long story short: You are right. Straight-forward case works as expected!

Answer (score 10):

It's true that `Executor.map()` will not wait for all futures to finish. Because it returns a lazy iterator like @MisterMiyagi said.

But we can accomplish this by using `with`:

```py
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def hello(i):
    time.sleep(i)
    print(i)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor.map(hello, [1, 2, 3])
print("finish")

# output
# 1
# 2
# 3
# finish
```

As you can see, `finish` is printed after `1,2,3`. It works because `Executor` has a `__exit__()` method, [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5618c81e139419b4665dc1f1e8a468738546f542/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L635-L637) is

```py
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.shutdown(wait=True)
    return False
```

the `shutdown` [method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5618c81e139419b4665dc1f1e8a468738546f542/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L216-L236) of `ThreadPoolExecutor` is

```py
def shutdown(self, wait=True, *, cancel_futures=False):
    with self._shutdown_lock:
        self._shutdown = True
        if cancel_futures:
            # Drain all work items from the queue, and then cancel their
            # associated futures.
            while True:
                try:
                    work_item = self._work_queue.get_nowait()
                except queue.Empty:
                    break
                if work_item is not None:
                    work_item.future.cancel()

        # Send a wake-up to prevent threads calling
        # _work_queue.get(block=True) from permanently blocking.
        self._work_queue.put(None)
    if wait:
        for t in self._threads:
            t.join()
shutdown.__doc__ = _base.Executor.shutdown.__doc__
```

So by using `with`, we can get the ability to wait until all futures finish.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your kind reply. I am wrong, `.map()` is not blocking. I misunderstood it. I have updated my answer to use `with` to accomplish the `wait` job.

Comment: The problem with this approach is if any exception is thrown by the tasks run by map, it will be eaten if the generator returned by `map` is not exhausted.