# How to copy list of files in parallel to list of destinations? Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have `src_list` and `dst_list`, two lists of the same length.

`src_list` contains paths to existing files.

`dst_list` contains paths to maybe existing files to maybe overwrite (not folders!).

`src_list[i]` should correspond to `dst_list[i]`.

I want to copy every `src_list[i]` to `dst_list[i]`, in (multiprocessing, not threading) parallel.

I want the call to be blocking, meaning all processes should be joined  before moving on.

---

Examples of lists:

```
src_list = [

r"/data/one/f1.txt",
r"/data/one/f2.txt",
r"/data/two/f3.txt",
r"/data/three/f4.txt",
r"/data/four/five/f5.txt",
]

dst_list = [

r"/out1/f1.txt",
r"/out2/two/three/pook.txt",
r"/data/foo/bar/baz/f333.txt",
r"/kiko/f4",
r"/data/four/five/f5.txt",
]
```

really, just just paths to files. Please assume the lists are ~1000-5000 elements long.

---

What I seem to lack is the correct API call to parallelize over two iterables.

Comment: Do you want to copy *the files* whose paths are in a list to *the paths* in another list, or do you want to copy *the file names* which are in a list to another list?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want to copy the *files* whose paths are given in `src_list` to the location (and name) provided in `dst_list`. The files in `dst` may or may not already exist. overwrite if they do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Full answer, based on [@tibipin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71203542/913098). This one also creates the `dst` folder structure if needed.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import shutil 
from typing import Iterable


def copy_single_file_create_dirs(src, dst):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dst), exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)


def copy_src_to_dst_overwrite_parallel(
        existing_src_files: Iterable[str],
        dst_files: Iterable[str],
        max_workers=None,
):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        executor.map(copy_single_file_create_dirs, existing_src_files, dst_files)
```

The `copy_single_file_create_dirs` function can't be defined as an inner function because then it needs to be pickled which doesn't work. This is the cleanest I could get.

Answer (score 5):

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from shutil import copyfile

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(copyfile, src_list, dst_list)
```

If you want to limit the number of processes that are working on this you can pass a `max_workers` argument inside the `ProcessPoolExecutor()` method.

Comment: How can I set the number of workers?

Comment: `with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor` becomes `with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor`

Comment: is `max_workers==0` the same as `max_workers is None`? and thanks :)

Comment: @Gulzar If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine. If max_workers is less than or equal to 0, then a ValueError will be raised. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor

Comment: Also, is this blocking? Meaning if after the `with` I were to `print("hi")`, will the print always occur after all copies?

Comment: @Gulzar Pretty sure this is blocking.

Comment: @user56700 can you link to the relevant doc? Couldn't find this stated anywhere

Comment: @Gulzar Well, couldn't find any, hence the "pretty sure", this is merely based on what I remember.

Comment: @Gulzar Check this question and answers + comments, gives good insight, but not much documentation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532411/how-do-i-wait-for-threadpoolexecutor-map-to-finish

Comment: This doesn't work, because `copyfile` expects the entire path to exist instead of creating it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import shutil

def parallel_copy(src_lst, dst_list):
    if not src_lst or not dst_list or len(src_lst) != len(dst_list):
        raise ValueError('Cannot process inputs.')

    processes = [Process(target=shutil.copyfile, args=(src, dst)) for src, dst in zip(src_lst, dst_list)]
    [p.start() for p in processes]
    [p.join() for p in processes]
```

Comment: Please assume many thousands of files. This would spawn many more processes than would be useful for speedup

Comment: @Gulzar You're right, considering that point, I think tibipin answer is the best.